# Is there an online code coloring service?

Tags: c#, php, javascript, wordpress

I would like to know if there is an online service where we paste the code and it generates back the colored HTML source code for that code. It could be PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, C, and Java.

The idea is that once I have the colored HTML code, I could easily put that in my wordpress.com blog. I know about `[sourcecode language="whatever"]`, but I just wanted to know an online service that supports multiple languages. The **benefit** is that, I can choose any color style/theme from that online service for my code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also you can use http://tohtml.com/html/ or [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/demo.php)

Answer (score 14):

[Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is the code colorizer that Stack Overflow uses.

Comment: But that's not online is it?

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at SyntaxHighligher. It uses JavaScript so it's not using your own server's resources and supports a bunch of color schemes. http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter

The problem with putting your code in a generator on another website is that if you change it somewhere you have to put it back in, which can become tedious.

Answer (score 4):

[CodeColorizer](http://www.chami.com/colorizer/) is one.

Answer (score 3):

You may mean a code pasting services such as [Pastie](http://pastie.org).

Answer (score 3):

I recently found http://hilite.me. I like it, because there is an option for formatting text--useful when you are posting a configuration file or a series of commands.

From a WordPress standpoint, I've been trying to trim back the number of plugins I'm running after a scan on pingdom.com showed how much time my page loads were taking because of a syntax highlighting plugin--and I rarely post code so it was a really not worth it.

I like the idea of inserting code blocks as pure HTML in the post, because you aren't required to have that plugin in the future and I'd assume won't impact page load times.

Comment: Very nice converter, thanks for posting your answer

Answer (score 2):

I use [WP-syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) for WordPress. It works great for me.

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but I thought I'd mention it here if anyone is looking for syntax hightlighting in WordPress.

From the usage description:

> Wrap code blocks with <pre lang="LANGUAGE" line="1"> and </pre>
> where LANGUAGE is a GeSHi supported
> language syntax.
> The line attribute is optional.